AtCoderの実行時間についての質問 (ABC351 D 問題)
https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc351/tasks/abc351_d
上記の問題 (ABC351 D 問題) において、以下２つのコードでなぜ実行時間が異なるかがわかりません。
２つのコードで変えた部分はi,j成分における上下左右の値の探し方にあり、他はほぼ同じです。

1つ目のコード
コード内で定義したaroundという関数を用いる

2つ目のコード
i,jに[(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)]をそれぞれ足してそれらがH×Wの範囲内かどうか判定する


私は計算量という観点から考えて、一回（i,j)成分の周りの値をさがすにあたり1つ目のコードのaround関数は最低2回（0<i<H-1,j=0の時）、最高でも４回（i=H,j=W)と考えました。
それに対して、2つ目のコードはi,jにそれぞれ[(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)]を足し、足した値をI, Jとすると（0<=I<H and 0<=J<W）を満たしているかどうかを計算することで最初に足す計算と比較する計算で計１２回分の計算が必要になり、後者のほうが計算量が多いと感じていました。
しかし、結果は逆だったのでなぜそのような結果になったのかお尋ねしたいです。わかる方がいらっしゃいましたら何卒よろしくお願いします。

コード 1
下記のコードで実行すると実行時間超過で間違いになります。
import copy
import sys
import random
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**9)

H,W=list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
A=[input() for _ in range(H)]
def around(i,j):
  if 0<i<H-1:
    if j==0:
      B=[(i+1,j),(i-1,j),(i,j+1)]
    elif 0<j<W-1:
      B=[(i+1,j),(i-1,j),(i,j+1),(i,j-1)]
    else:
      B=[(i+1,j),(i-1,j),(i,j-1)]
  elif i==0:
     if j==0:
      B=[(i+1,j),(i,j+1)]
     elif 0<j<W-1:
      B=[(i+1,j),(i,j+1),(i,j-1)]
     else:
      B=[(i+1,j),(i,j-1)]
  else:
     if j==0:
      B=[(i-1,j),(i,j+1)]
     elif 0<j<W-1:
      B=[(i-1,j),(i,j+1),(i,j-1)]
     else:
      B=[(i-1,j),(i,j-1)]
  return B
  
B=[[0]*W for _ in range(H)] 
for i in range(H):
  for j in range(W):
    if A[i][j]=="#":
      B[i][j]=1
      for x  in around(i,j):
        B[x[0]][x[1]]=1
def ans(i,j,k):
  if B[i][j]!=2:
    k+=1
    B[i][j]+=1
    if B[i][j]==2:
      C.append((i,j))
    else:
      B[i][j]+=1
      for x in around(i,j):
        k=ans(x[0],x[1],k)
  return k
k=0
for i in range(H):
  for j in range(W):
    C=[]
    t=ans(i,j,0)
    if k<t:
      k=t
    for i,j in C:
      B[i][j]=1
print(k)

コード 2
このコードだと正解になります。
import sys
import random
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**9)

H,W=list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
A=[input() for _ in range(H)]

  
B=[[0]*W for _ in range(H)] 
for i in range(H):
  for j in range(W):
    if A[i][j]=="#":
      B[i][j]=1
      for y,x  in [(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)]:
        I=i+y
        J=j+x
        if 0<=I<H and 0<=J<W:
          B[I][J]=1
def ans(i,j,k):
  if B[i][j]!=2:
    k+=1
    B[i][j]+=1
    if B[i][j]==2:
      C.append((i,j))
    else:
      B[i][j]+=1
      for y,x in [(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)]:
        I=i+y
        J=j+x
        if 0<=I<H and 0<=J<W:
          k=ans(I,J,k)
  return k
k=0
for i in range(H):
  for j in range(W):
    C=[]
    t=ans(i,j,0)
    if k<t:
      k=t
    for i,j in C:
      B[i][j]=1
print(k)


コード1では、コード2だと不要な処理を追加で実施する必要があるため、遅くなっています。
具体的には、コード1のaround関数内にて、毎回複数個のタプルとリストを作成する処理が、遅い原因です。それに対し、コード2の場合は、固定のリスト[(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)]をループに使用するので、タプル・リストを毎回作成する必要がありません。
実際に両者のコードを逆アセンブルすると、違いが分かります。
コード1で、around関数の返却値のリストを作成する処理は、例えば以下のようになっています(長さ4のリストを作成する部分)。BUILD_TUPLEが4回、BUILD_LISTが1回呼ばれているのが分かります。
 13     >>  102 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
            104 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
            106 BINARY_ADD
            108 LOAD_FAST                1 (j)
            110 BUILD_TUPLE              2
            112 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
            114 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
            116 BINARY_SUBTRACT
            118 LOAD_FAST                1 (j)
            120 BUILD_TUPLE              2
            122 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
            124 LOAD_FAST                1 (j)
            126 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
            128 BINARY_ADD
            130 BUILD_TUPLE              2
            132 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
            134 LOAD_FAST                1 (j)
            136 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
            138 BINARY_SUBTRACT
            140 BUILD_TUPLE              2
            142 BUILD_LIST               4

それに対し、コード2で[(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)]を参照する処理は、定数を呼び出す以下の1行だけです。タプル作成・リスト作成が一切行われていないことが分かります。
 67         126 LOAD_CONST               9 (((1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)))

なお、コード1の方が加減算や条件分岐の回数が少なくなるのは事実ですが、タプルやリストを作成する処理の方が重いため、そちらの影響の方が大きくなります。
実際、タプルやリストを作成しないようにコード1を無理やり書き換えると、コード2よりも速くなります。ただし、コード1は1行1列のマス目に対応していないので、実際に提出すると一部REとなります。
import copy
import sys
import random
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**9)

H,W=list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
A=[input() for _ in range(H)]
def around(i,j):
  if 0<i<H-1:
    if j==0:
      B=(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1)
    elif 0<j<W-1:
      B=(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)
    else:
      B=(1,0),(-1,0),(0,-1)
  elif i==0:
     if j==0:
      B=(1,0),(0,1)
     elif 0<j<W-1:
      B=(1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)
     else:
      B=(1,0),(0,-1)
  else:
     if j==0:
      B=(-1,0),(0,1)
     elif 0<j<W-1:
      B=(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)
     else:
      B=(-1,0),(0,-1)
  return B
  
B=[[0]*W for _ in range(H)] 
for i in range(H):
  for j in range(W):
    if A[i][j]=="#":
      B[i][j]=1
      for y,x in around(i,j):
        B[i+y][j+x]=1
def ans(i,j,k):
  if B[i][j]!=2:
    k+=1
    B[i][j]+=1
    if B[i][j]==2:
      C.append((i,j))
    else:
      B[i][j]+=1
      for y,x in around(i,j):
        k=ans(i+y,j+x,k)
  return k
k=0
for i in range(H):
  for j in range(W):
    C=[]
    t=ans(i,j,0)
    if k<t:
      k=t
    for i,j in C:
      B[i][j]=1
print(k)

